# Can't adjust screen brightness?

Tags: windows-7, networking, display

My laptop was working fine.
Yesterday, I installed VS2008, Google Chrome, and MSDN.
Today, when I start my laptop, the screen brightness goes very low when I reach the "enter your Windows 7 password" page.

I have a Sony Vaio vgn-nr11s/s

Also, my wireless connection and LAN seems to have vanished into thin air.

I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it'd happen but it sounds like maybe it might be as simple as re-installing drivers.  If you wireless and lan connections are screwed up it's possible other things got messed up too.  Like maybe some kind of monitor driver that lets you set brightness settings or something (or possibly the display adapter).  I'd go to sony's site and grab the latest drivers for everything that isn't working, re-install them, and see if anything changes before trying to tweak your video card stuff.  Worse case scenario, you might be able to go into your graphics cards settings utility that came with your video card (if it's a card that has that sort of thing) and turn up your brightness that way.  I realize you don't have networking working but you were able to post this so maybe you have a way of getting the drivers.  They might have come on a cd that came with the pc also.

Also, doing a system restore before all that, might fix it even quicker.